# Create a file as a different user and group

Tags: bash, permissions, su, chown

I have a bash script that has to rsync to download files writing them locally, and then needs to set the owner to apache, and the group to a particular user group (that apache is not a member of).

Is there a way to create those files with those ownerships as they're being written by the rsync process, **without having to go through and change them after the fact using chown?**  There are so many files that the time it takes to go through them later is prohibitive.

I have to do this for multiple user groups, so I shouldn't be adding apache to these groups, and certainly can't make all of them the default group.

In other words:  is there a way root can create a file as user X and group Y when X is not a member of Y?

I've tried using runuser, but I'm unable to set the group (presumably because apache doesn't belong to the group).

I know you can use chmod to change permissions and add any user/group combination.  What I'm asking is if there is a way to open a file for writing and use any user/group combo while creating it.

Attempt using sudo:

```
[root@centos7 tmp]# groups angelo
angelo : angelo wheel
[root@centos7 tmp]# groups apache
apache : apache
[root@centos7 tmp]# sudo -u angelo -g apache touch angelo-file
Sorry, user root is not allowed to execute '/bin/touch angelo-file' as angelo:apache on centos7
[root@centos7 tmp]# ls -ld angelo-file
ls: cannot access angelo-file: No such file or directory
[root@centos7 tmp]# sudo -u angelo -g angelo touch angelo-file
[root@centos7 tmp]# ls -ld angelo-file
-rw-r--r-- 1 angelo angelo 0 Nov 12 03:13 angelo-file
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File owner must belong to file group?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71032/file-owner-must-belong-to-file-group)

Comment: That question is asking about the filesystem.  You can chmod the file to give any user/group you want.  I want to know if you can open a file descriptor acting as any user/group combo.  If it is possible, then I haven't found out how.

Comment: Do you mean from C?  Or from Bash?  Have you tried just using `sudo` with the `-g` switch?

Comment: I mean using normal Linux tools or commands.  I would accept an answer that could verify that you could only do this in C because no tools exist.  But I also wouldn't be surprised if you can't even do it in C and this is not an available request through the API.  sudo with -g will work if the user is a member of the group, but seems to be disallowed if not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to create a file as a specific user and group without using `chown`, you can use `sudo` and specify the user and group:

```
sudo -u \#49 -g \#58 touch /tmp/something
```

Note that the user you specify must have permission to write to the directory where you attempt this.

---

Or, you can start a shell as the current user, with the group set to something else:

```
sudo runuser "$USER" -g somegroup
```

I tried this on a Vagrant box with success:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo runuser "$USER" -g floppy
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ touch testfile
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ ls -l testfile
-rw-r--r--. 1 vagrant floppy 0 Nov  9 15:57 testfile
[vagrant@localhost ~]$
```

This is despite the "vagrant" user not being part of the "floppy" group.

Comment: Oh snap.  You did it with a combination of runuser and sudo.  I don't know how you figured that out.  sudo -u and -g doesn't seem to work though

Comment: Not sure why I can't just run touch in-line, but this seems to work:  sudo runuser "$USER" -g floppy bash -c "touch testfile"

Comment: @Angelo, yeah, to be honest I thought this was a silly question, but I've just tried several variations on this and found how tricky it can be.  I appear to have gotten the right approach on the first try.  :)

Answer (score 5):

```
$ sudo install -o angelo -g apache /dev/null angelo-file
```

Works for me on `centos 6`, install version 8.4. Here the install is "copying" the (known to always be empty) `/dev/null` file to the target, thereby creating your empty file, while in same/single command setting target file's owner and group, because it's run as root via sudo.

Read more about it via: `man install` or `install --help`. It can create directories, and set permission modes too, in same/single command. The install command is frequently used in build tools, like makefiles.

You may like to use option `-T` too, so if target preexists but is a directory, it will fail with an error, and not create empty `angelo-file/null` instead.

EDIT: OP asked about rsync, duh. Since rsync 3.1.2 see the options like `--chmod`, `--chown`, `--usermap`, `--groupmap`. (For `centos 6` I can get the newer rsync from the iUS repo).

Comment: This would be another solution in my case if I could run install in such a way that it allowed another process to write the files.  (In my case, I needed the files to be rsync'd and written with the right owner/group on the first shot.)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you run the script with elevated privileges, there should be no problem. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
touch foobar
chown www-data:sudo foobar
```

If you run as a normal user, it will fail:

```
$ ./foo.sh 
chown: changing ownership of `foobar': Operation not permitted
```

But if you run it as root, it works fine:

```
$ sudo foo.sh
$ ls -l foobar
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data sudo 26M Sep 17 17:34 foobar
```

Comment: I want to do it without chown:  "rather than having to go through and change them"

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bash script, run it as root and fix the ownership inside the script himself.

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'setuid' on a c wrapper to chmod it, but this is NOT recommended as it's a very HUGE security hole unless it's extremely restricted in programming.